# Python count number of periods in a series

Tags: series

I am having an error while counting the number of periods in a series.
I have tried this

```
series = pd.Series(['how. are. you. today.', 'i. am. fine.', 'thank. you.'])
count = series.str.count('.')
```

Expected results are

```
0 4
1 3
2 2
```

but instead I get

```
0 21
1 12
2 11
```

How do I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
series = pd.Series(['how. are. you. today.', 'i. am. fine.', 'thank. you.'])
count = series.str.count('\.')
```